# Woocommerce количество товаров в категории

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wordpress-плагины

Я не могу найти, как добавить пользователю возможность выбирать, какое количество товаров отображать в категории на странице. Ранее это было решено плагином, насколько я понимаю, https://wordpress.org/plugins/woocommerce-products-per-page/. Но теперь это встроено в Wocommerce или я не прав?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В стандартных настройках Wocommerce, на сколько я помню, такого нет. Плагины которые долго не обновлялись я не советую использовать. Попробуйте вставить этот код в `functions.php`

```
//save and load the chosen option from session
function jc_get_products_per_page(){

    global $woocommerce;

    $default = 5;
    $count = $default;
    $options = jc_get_products_per_page_options();

    // capture form data and store in session
    if(isset($_POST['jc-woocommerce-products-per-page'])){ 
        // set products per page from dropdown
        $products_max = intval($_POST['jc-woocommerce-products-per-page']);
        if($products_max != 0 && $products_max >= -1){
            $woocommerce->session->jc_product_per_page = $products_max;
            return $products_max;
        }
    }
    // load product limit from session
    if(isset($woocommerce->session->jc_product_per_page)){
        // set products per page from woo session
        $products_max = intval($woocommerce->session->jc_product_per_page);
        if($products_max != 0 && $products_max >= -1){
            return $products_max;
        }
    }
    return $count;
}
add_filter('loop_shop_per_page','jc_get_products_per_page');

//set the options for the dropdown
function jc_get_products_per_page_options(){
    $options = apply_filters( 'jc_products_per_page', array(
        5 => __('5', 'woocommerce'),
        10 => __('10', 'woocommerce'),
        15 => __('15', 'woocommerce'),
        20 => __('20', 'woocommerce')
    ));

    return $options;
}
//display the dropdown on front-end
function jc_woocommerce_products_per_page(){

    $options = jc_get_products_per_page_options();

    $current_value = jc_get_products_per_page();
    ?>
    <div class="products-per-page">
        <span>View:</span>
        <form action="" method="POST" class="woocommerce-products-per-page">
            <select name="jc-woocommerce-products-per-page" onchange="this.form.submit()">
            <?php foreach($options as $value => $name): ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $value; ?>" <?php selected($value, $current_value); ?>><?php echo $name; ?></option>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </form>
    </div>
    <?php
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop', 'jc_woocommerce_products_per_page', 1);
add_filter('loop_shop_per_page','jc_get_products_per_page', 99);
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо